# Get Envelope ReadWrite Set in Hyperledger Fabric Java

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm working on a Java application for Hyperledger Fabric.

I have a `Common.Envelope` object, I need to extract the Read Write set and any other information from it.

I was reading about the BlockInfo class in the Java sdk, but I'm unsure in how I can use this.

How can I get the ReadWrite set from a Common.Envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't going to answer this as you specifically want answers on hyperledger fabric java sdk. However, Since there wasn't a useful answer yet, I'll explain how to do it and you can replicate the process in Java with same workflow.

Steps to get `common.ConfigUpdate` from `common.Envelope`:

- let `envelope` be assigned `common.Envelope` struct, so `envelope.Payload` is type `common.Payload`.Unmarshall this to a variable `payload`.
- `payload.Data` contains `common.ConfigUpdateEnvelope`, unmarshall it to a variable `configUpdateEnvelop`.
- `configUpdateEnvelop.ConfigUpdate` has type `common.ConfigUpdate`, unmarshall it to a variable `ConfigUpdate`.
- `ConfigUpdate` had `ChannelId` type `string`, `ReadSet` type `common.ConfigGroup` and `WriteSet` type `common.ConfigGroup`. Unmarshall whatever you want to required variables.

Hope this helped.